# Akka Concatenating Arrays from Generic Messages

Tags: scala, akka, actor

In the below code I have a main actor that maintains an array and it creates a child actor which creates an array and sends it back inside of a message which I then want to concatenate to the array that the main actor maintains. I wanted to keep the messages generic so it could work for any type of array.

```
object ActorMain {

  case class addThese[T](len: Int, content: T)

}

class ActorMain extends Actor {

  import ActorMain._
  import ReceivingActor._

  var myArray: Array[Double] = Array.empty

  val child = context.actorOf(Props[ReceivingActor], "child")

  child ! addThese(6, 5.0)


  def receive = {

    case result(plusOne) => {

      myArray ++= plusOne

    }
  }

}


object ReceivingActor {

  case class result[T](el: Array[T])

}

class ReceivingActor extends Actor {

  import ActorMain._

  import ReceivingActor._

  def receive = {
    case addThese(len, content) => {

      val res = Array.fill(len)(content)

      sender ! result(res)

    }
  }

}
```

An error occurs during the concatenation `myArray ++= plusOne`.  This creates an error because `plusOne` is of type `Any`.  I have tried replacing this line with `myArray ++= plusOne.asInstanceOf[Array[Double]]` but this gives the error `java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [D`.  Is there anyway of doing this while still keeping the messages generic?  It seems as though there needs to be a way for the main actor to know the exact type of the array that it is receiving in the message, but I don't know if this is possible if the message is generic

Answer (score 2):

How about parameterizing myArray as an Array[T]? You'd need to parameterize ActorMain and ReceivingActor accordingly.

Another good thing to do is to sprinkle in more explicit type information. Type inference is great when banging out new code but explicit types can be very helpful when dealing with problems like this. If using explicit types, would you use Array.fill[Double], Array.fill[Object] or Array.fill[T]?

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
case result(plusOne: Array[Double]) => {
  myArray ++= plusOne
}
case result(plusOne: Array[Object]) => ...
```

Note that `Array` is the only generic type for which it works like this.

> It seems as though there needs to be a way for the main actor to know the exact type of the array that it is receiving in the message

The exact type you are sending and receiving is `Array[Object]` (written as `[Ljava.lang.Object` in the exception message), since `content` has type `Object` (`Any` in Scala, but it ends up as `Object` in the JVM).

Comment: This gives me the error ```Error:(23, 26) scrutinee is incompatible with pattern type;
 found   : Array[Double]
 required: Array[Any]
Note: Double <: Any, but class Array is invariant in type T.
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: Any`. (SLS 3.2.10)
    case result(plusOne: Array[Double]) => {```
                         ^

Comment: Ah, right. You can work around this by using `case class result(el: Array[_])`, where `Array[_]` means "Array of an arbitrary type".or casting `plusOne` to `Array[_]` before matching on its type. Not necessarily a good idea in general, but in this case you aren't losing type-safety anyway.